Salesforce Sharing Rules and Restrictions
I am trying to restrict access to an account with below configurations:

I have removed 'View All' permission from all user profiles (except
Admin)
OWD for Account is Private.
Sharing rule added to open access to all users except where the account's
privacy is marked as True.

I have created a test record with System Admin profile and my role is above all in the hierarchy. This record is marked for Privacy at field level.
When I login as a user who has a role below in the hierarchy, I am still able to view thsi record.
What am I missing here? Any suggestion is appreciated!
(I have made sure that the user's profile has access to the field that is being used to determine privacy of the record.)

step 1 -- click the Sharing button on the Account to see whom it is shared and why

If you don't have the sharing button on he page layout you can always get to it via URL: https://www.simplysfdc.com/2015/07/salesforce-sharing-button-url.html
